# How can I sort function using priority queue in C++/C?

Tags: c++

I want to array "functions" by priority

E.g SetNumber1 is first
SetNumber2 is second
ReadNumbers is last

////////////////

```
priority_queue < ??? > Q
Q.push(ReadNumbers());
Q.push(SetNumber2());
Q.push(SetNumber1());
```

i want to exec in order to SetNumber1() , SetNumber2(), ReadNumbers()

Thanks.

and sorry about my english skils, I'am korean, i'm not good at english

Comment: The example is too simplified. You can just call `SetNumber1(); SetNumber2(); ReadNumbers();`, so there is no need for a priority queue here.

Comment: 1. You need to associate a priority with a function, by some means; 2. You shouldn't call the functions when adding them to the queue. There's not enough detail to say anything very specific. For instance, is the "priority" tied to a function itself, or to a specific function call?

Comment: You need a way to assign priorities to the functions. It's unclear what you expect. You can store function pointers in a queue, but you cannot compare them in any meaningful way. With how you've written it here, perhaps you want a stack instead? https://godbolt.org/z/a49rxMa3T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

std::priority_queue works with a compare function which can't work with the given functions. You need to define your own priorities as an enum and then you can put the pair of the prio and function in an std::multimap so all functions can be called according to their prio. You can put the pair also in a prio-q but then you still need a compare function that only works on the prio.

e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <functional>
    
enum class prio { HI, MID, LO };

int main()
{
    std::multimap<prio, std::function<void()>> prio_mmap;

    prio_mmap.insert(std::make_pair(prio::MID, []{ std::cout << "MID1\n"; }));
    prio_mmap.insert(std::make_pair(prio::LO, []{ std::cout << "LO\n"; }));
    prio_mmap.insert(std::make_pair(prio::HI, []{ std::cout << "HI\n"; }));
    prio_mmap.insert(std::make_pair(prio::MID, []{ std::cout << "MID2\n"; }));
    
    for (const auto& p: prio_mmap)
    {
        p.second();
    }
}
```